# whats wrong with my connect four code for a cpu on medium difficulty

Tags: python

For this code first of all. drop_piece checks if the column is full. The other helper functions are used to find out if there's a win and potentially place a token in it. cpu_player_easy places a random move. draw_checker checks if there's a draw. When running test cases i keep getting a type error saying that "TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'".  Here's my code and I am kind of lost:

```
import random
def drop_piece(board, player, column): #(start, stop, end)
    for row in range(5, -1, -1): #iterates and starts at 5 and makes it's way up the row by taking away 1 till it gets to the top and which would have a -1
           if board[row][column - 1] == 0: #makes sure that the column directly below does not have a token on it
                board[row][column - 1] = player 
                return True
    else:
        return False    



def cpu_player_easy(board, player):
  while True:
    column = random.randint(1,7)
    if drop_piece(board, player, column): ## calls on this function and says if that's true then return the columns
      return column

def vertical_Win():
    for row in range(0,3):  
        for column in range(0,7):
            if board[row][column] == board[row + 1][column] == board[row + 2][column] == board[row + 3][column] and board[row][column] != 0:    
                if board[row][column] == 1:
                    return column

def horizontal_Win():
    for row in range(6):    
        for column in range(1, 4):
            if board[row][column] == board[row][column + 1] == board[row][column + 2] == board[row][column + 3] and board[row][column] != 0:    
                if board[row][column] == 1:
                    return column
                else:
                    return None

def diagonal_Win_TL_To_BR():
    for row in range(3):    
        for column in range(1 , 4):
            if board[row][column - 1] == board[row + 1][column - 0] == board[row + 2][column + 1] == board[row + 3][column + 2] and board[row][column - 1] != 0:
                if board[row][column - 1] == 1:
                    return column
                else:
                    return None

def diagonal_Win_Tr_To_BL():
    for row in range(0,3): ## from top to bottom
        for column in range(3, 7): ## from left to right
            if board[row][column] == board[row + 1][column - 1] == board[row + 2][column - 2] == board[row + 3][column - 3] and board[row][column] != 0:
                if board[row][column] == 1:
                    return column
                else:
                    return None

def draw_checker(board):
    for row in range(0,6):
        for column in range(0,7):
            if board[row][column] == 0:
                return None
        
def create_board():
 number_of_rows = 6
 number_of_columns = 7
 arr_2d =[] ##this is the 2d array which we will store the zeroes in.
 for x in range(number_of_rows):## responsible for the rows
   column_elements = [] ## empty list that will hold the elements of the current row
   for y in range(number_of_columns):## responsible for the columns
     column_elements.append(0)
   arr_2d.append(column_elements)## appends the column_elements list to the "arr_2d" list representing a new row in the 2d array
 return arr_2d


def cpu_player_medium(board, player):
    """
    Executes a move for the CPU on medium difficulty.
    It first checks for an immediate win and plays that move if possible. 
    If no immediate win is possible, it checks for an immediate win 
    for the opponent and blocks that move. If neither of these are 
    possible, it plays a random move.

    :param board: The game board, 2D list of 6x7 dimensions.
    :param player: The player whose turn it is, integer value of 1 or 2.
    :return: Column that the piece was dropped into, int.
    """
    while draw_checker(board) == False:
        if vertical_Win() or horizontal_Win() or diagonal_Win_TL_To_BR() or diagonal_Win_Tr_To_BL():
            return column
        else:
            cpu_player_easy(board, player)
```

When running test cases i keep getting a type error saying that "TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'".  Here's my code and I am kind of lost in general

Comment: This is just a bunch of functions that are never called.  Please make a [mcve] and include the traceback of the error message.

Comment: @MarkTolonen so are my helper functions not useful in this scenario

Comment: No, as the current answer points out, there is no <= in this code. Provide code that when copied and run **without changes** it produces the error claimed.  This code cannot cause the error claimed.

Answer (score 1):

Since the code you posted contains exactly *zero* occurrences of `<=`, it's probably in the test cases. You need to show us those.

In addition, Python unit testing frameworks will generally tell you the exact line where the error occurred, that can be used to track down the issue. That (the output in full) should also be in the question.

---

Based on experience, *likely* candidates are the win-checking functions, such as `vertical_Win()`, which return the "thing" (row, column, etc) where a win occurred, or (explicitly or implicitly) `None` if there was no win in that "thing".

There's a good chance your test case will contain something like:

```py
# Check any win is on the board.
vwin = vertical_Win()
assert 0 <= vwin <= 6
```

If your invocation of the win-checking function returned `None`, that would result in the error you're seeing. If that *is* the case, you should take that into account, possibly with something like:

```py
# Check any win is on the board.
vwin = vertical_Win()
assert vwin is not None and 0 <= vwin <= 6
```

But, again, this depends on your *actual* test cases, which we can't (currently) see. So it's supposition, but at least educated supposition :-)

---

Another possibility is the use of `column` in the `cpu_player_easy` and `cpu_player_medium` functions.

Though the first of those returns the column in which the win took place, it's not saved anywhere when the second makes the call. I'd normally expect it to raise a `NameError` as `column` shouldn't exist at the point it's returned from the second <sup>(1)</sup> but, regardless, you need to ensure information is passed around correctly rather than discarded.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> A possible exception to this is if `column` is declared globally somewhere but, if that were the case, none of the attempted assignments you make to it will happen anyway. That's because any change to a non-`global`-marked variable in a function creates and affects a new *local* variable, not the global one.

Comment: I invocated that function and it gave me the same error as above mentioned

Comment: @j1400: invoked *which* function, exactly, and how? As already stated, none of the functions given can possibly generate that error. Please post unit tests and the full text of the error.